# Why is index on Number bigger than on String?

Tags: mongodb

mongo db 1.4.1

2 collections, identical data, but use different data type (foo - string, bar - number) for field "x":

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({x:1});
> db.bar.ensureIndex({x:1});
> db.foo.stats();
{
    "ns" : "impressions.foo",
    "count" : 50000,
    "size" : 23519184,
    "avgObjSize" : 470.38368,
    "storageSize" : 37797888,
    "numExtents" : 8,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 15290368,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2526384,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 1463504,
        "x_1" : 1062880
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.bar.stats()
{
    "ns" : "impressions.bar",
    "count" : 50000,
    "size" : 21594256,
    "avgObjSize" : 431.88512,
    "storageSize" : 22507520,
    "numExtents" : 7,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 11325440,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2730784,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 1463504,
        "x_1" : 1267280
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

x_1 is bigger in case 2, whereas you would expect the opposite?

Comment: Why would you expect the opposite?

Comment: I have got to admit that is kind of confusing, I mean the average object size is smaller, in fact all stats are smaller for numbner except size, in fact size does not relate very well to the rest of the data in the stats output. @DekDekku probably because it takes less bytes to represent numbers than it does strings

Comment: It can take less bytes to represent a string if the string is small (and it wouldn't surprise me if all the strings in the collection are "foo" and "bar") while numbers always take the same amount of space. But I can't check the actual data, so...

Comment: @DekDekku
"x" is actually a number [0;1000];
foo collection has all fields as strings, whereas bar has all of them as numbers; so the case is indexing "1" vs 1
that's where all the "space" comes from; but i was expecting the index to be smaller as well since it takes less bytes to write a number than a string (given mongo uses UTF8)

Comment: I think representing numbers in UTF-8 gives the same representation as ASCII, 1 byte per character, but I might be wrong. While all integer numbers use 4 bytes.

Comment: UTF8 Strings representing numbers "0"-"1000" will take between 1 and 4 bytes each, specifically 2894 bytes in total for a single 0-1000 set. 1000 integers take 8000 bytes (64 bit signed int, or double) or 4000 bytes if you use 32-bit ints. Even though the documents are smaller in this case the index should be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The int value ( or long ) in indexes are stored as double in mongodb, which I guess is 8 bytes. So this might be the cause of larger index size as compared to the string value.

Check the source code.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/key.cpp#L312

Answer (score 0):

The integer is being stored as a bson type 16 which is a 32-bit integer. If the integer is a categorical value which you can store a a string that is only one character long, it should only be 8-bit (UTF-8 string).